# Django code to execute only in development and production

Tags: python, django

I need to execute some housekeeping code but only in development or production environment. Unfortunately all management commands execute similar to runserver. Is there any clean way to classify what is the execution environment and run the code selectively.

I saw some solutions like 'runserver' in sys.argv
but it does not work for production. And does not look very clean.
Does django provide anything to classify all these different scenarios code is executing at?

**Edit**

The real problem is we need to initialise our local cache once the apps are loaded with some data that are frequently accessed. In general I want to fetch DB for some specific information and cache it (currently in memory). The issue is, when it tries to fetch DB, the table may not be created, in fact there may not be migration files created at all. So, when I run makemigrations/migrate, it will run this code which tries to fetch from DB, and throw error saying table does not exist. But if I can't run makemigration/migrate, there will be no table, it is kind of a loop I'm trying to avoid. The part of code will run for all management commands, but I would like to restrict it's execution only to when the app is actually serving requests (that is when the cache is needed) and not for any management commands (including the user defined ones).

```python

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from my_app.signals import app_created


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'

    def ready(self):
        import my_app.signals
        # Code below should be executed only in actual app execution
        # And not in makemigration/migrate etc management commands
        app_created.send(sender=MyAppConfig, sent_by="MyApp")
```

```

Q) Send app created signal for app execution other than executions due to management commands like makemigrations, migrate, etc.

Comment: With how broad the question is currently written, I don't see why a simple conditional check for django's `DEBUG` setting wouldn't work. If there is any such reason I suggest updating the question with more information.

Comment: @FynnBecker Added an Edit to the question. See if it makes better sense now.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many different ways to do this. But generally when I create a production (or staging, or development) server I set an environment variable. And dynamically decide which settings file to load based on that environment variable.

Imagine something like this in a Django settings file:

```
import os

ENVIRONMENT = os.environ.get('ENVIRONMENT', 'development')
```

Then you can use

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.ENVIRONMENT == 'production':
    # do something only on production
```

Comment: when I run makemigrations with this approach, it will have 'development' environment. I need something that differentiates actual build/run commands from management commands.

Comment: I have updated the question for clarity. See if it has more information now for you to answer it.

Comment: You're going to have to put a if statement around your special cache loading code... I (from experience from four major Django projects in production) have a fully migrated database in 'development' and can use that environment to make and test migrations. The 'testing' environment is where a fully migrated env doesn't exist. And then tests might run migrations as required.

Answer (score 0):

Since, I did not get an convincing answer and I managed to pull off a solution, although not a 100% clean. I thought I would just share solution I ended up with.

```
import sys
from django.conf import settings

if (settings.DEBUG and 'runserver' in sys.argv) or not settings.DEBUG:
     """your code to run only in development and production"""
```

The rationale is you run the code if it is not in DEBUG mode no matter what. But if it is in DEBUG mode check if the process execution had runserver in the arguments.